# Why is Wordpress not uploading my file? $_FILE always null

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been searching for a similar question on SO but none were helping me solve my issue. I'll ask again here in case someone like me is in the same situation.

I'm trying to upload a file on wordpress. The file is sent to the server, when I upload it I can see it on my inspector:

[image]

However, if I'm doing a var_dump on $_FILE on the server it always returns null:

```
<?php
add_action('wp_ajax_form_candidat', 'form_candidat');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_form_candidat', 'form_candidat');

function form_candidat() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'wp_handle_upload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }
    check_ajax_referer('ajax_file_nonce', 'security');
    var_dump($_FILES);
    var_dump($_FILES['file']);

    $file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['file'], array( 'test_form' => false ));
    //...and so on
}
```

If I var_dump $file I'm getting:

File is empty. Please upload something more substantial. This error could also be caused by uploads being disabled in your php.ini or by post_max_size being defined as smaller than upload_max_filesize in php.ini.

I did a phpinfo(); but post_max_size = 64 MB and upload_max_filesize = 64 MB.

Where could this be coming from? My file is 2KB
Thanks

EDIT:
Here is the js code that triggers the upload:

```
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("security", secu);
formData.append("_wp_http_referer", referer);

formData.append("prenom", prenom);
formData.append("file", cv);
// more fields

$.ajax({
    url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
})
```

EDIT 2:

In my HTML the "cv" is the following input field:

```
<form class="formulaire margin-top" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="#" id="candidat_form">
<input id="cv" class="file" type="file" name="cv" accept="application/pdf">
// More stuff
```

EDIT 3:
in my JS i select only the first file:

```
cv = $('.form-input-wrapper #cv.file')[0].files[0];
    if(cv != undefined) {
        if( ( (cv.size / 1024) / 1024) > 2) {
            $('.file-cv').next('.error-message').css('display', 'block');
            cv = false;
        } else {
            $('.file-cv').next('.error-message').css('display', 'none');
        }
    }
```

EDIT 4:
A Huge thank you to the community and the people helping me solving this.
I've been switching this:

```
formData.append("file", cv);
```

to this:

```
formData.append('file', Array.from(cv));
```

However when I var_dump($_FILES) I still get array(0){};
Here is the inspector:

[image]

Comment: Most likely the script you're using for Ajax, please post that in the question

Comment: I agree with Josh above, but please also check all .ini directives. You only list two of several possible misconfigurations (also, what's your file size? under 64mb? assuming yes but not stated). You can find .ini config for file uploads here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads

Comment: Thanks, question updated.

Comment: @TCooper, yes my php.ini params are the same as what's specified in your link. Thank you.

Comment: I figured, afaik file_uploads is on be default, but seems an odd issue so thought it worth checking.

Comment: What is `cv`? Seems it's not a `File` but a `FileList`. I don't think PHP is able to handle that as an upload source

Comment: Do you get the same error if uploading to the media library or elsewhere?

Comment: Have you checked $_REQUEST and $_POST to see if any info for `file` made it through at all?

Comment: Can you post the html as well? i.e. is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` and `<input type="file"...`? To be honest I'm not sure that's required with AJAX setting the data encoding/type itself but might be worth checking.

Comment: @Phil, I've added the input field. Is there anything I should change to have it a FILE not a filelist?

Comment: I believe you need `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` to send files with jquerys ajax method

Comment: @JoshBonnick no, you don't. The presence of a `FormData` `data` property takes care of that automatically

Comment: @JoshBonnick, yes you are right, I have updated my question. My form does contain the enctype multipart..
I honestly think this is coming from a sysadmin issue. Like maybe the upload folder is not writable or who knows ...

Comment: @JoshBonnick I did var_dump on $_REQUEST and got that for my cv:  ["file"]=> string(17) "[object FileList]"

Comment: Try using `formData.append('file', Array.from(cv))` from what i've just read about FileList object, it should turn the files into something PHP can read

Comment: The question is, why is `cv` a `FileList` and not a single `File`. OP, try clearing your browser cache. Perhaps a previous version of your script wasn't selecting an individual file

Comment: How do you submit the form / trigger the AJAX upload? Are you making sure you're preventing the default form submit event from continuing?

Comment: @JoshBonnick Thank you for the suggestion. See edit 4

Comment: @Phil yes I do a e.preventDefault(); after the trigger of the on click event on the submit button.

Comment: I am thinking this could come from a server issue, like folder permissions or something in WP I'm not aware of that is preventing the upload from working. The $_REQUEST does have the file. but not $_FILES

Comment: Yeah, im stumped at this point, I've been here there and everywhere and this should work :/

Comment: Does your PHP config include a correct `upload_tmp_dir` setting?

Comment: That may be it, is this something I should check on php.ini? RIght now there is "no value" Could that be set up somewhere in WP? admin?